# Constructing a child object from parent object in C++

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, move-constructor

I am trying to construct a child class object from a base class object. I have tried the below code.

```
class A
{ 

public:
A();
A(A&& objectName) = default;
virtual void setint(int i);
virtual void getint();

int var;

};

class B: public A
{
public:
virtual void getint();
B(A&& objectName);

int j= 20;
};

A::A()
{

}

void A::setint(int i)
{
   var = i;
}

void A::getint()
{
qDebug()<<"From A Var"<<var;
}


void B::getint()
{
qDebug()<<"From B j"<<j;
qDebug()<<"From B Var"<<var;
}

B::B(A&& objectName): A(std::move(objectName))
{

}
```

And in my Main.cpp I am doing this

```
   #include <memory>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {

    A *obj = new A();
    obj->setint(10);
    obj->getint();

    A *obj1 = new B(std::move(*obj));

    obj->getint();

    obj1->getint();

    return 0;
    }


The result I get is 

From A Var 10 
From A Var 10 
From B j 20 
From B Var 10
```

My question is why am I getting the value of Var after  A *obj1 = new B(std::move(*obj)); this line. I thought the object pointed by obj must have been destructed.

Comment: please improve the formatting of the code sample.

Comment: There are several misconceptions in play here. First, you expect the object to be destroyed (it is not). Second, you expect to get some kind of error when you intentionally do a wrong thing like touching a destroyed object (sometimes you do, sometimes you don't).